# Firestore security rules: small delay in read access?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In my new Firestore based App I'm currently working on the implementation of security rules. After adding some first security rules, I experience the following behavior: when adding a read rule, after creation of the specified document it takes some time (seconds) before I'm allowed to read the object.

Security rules:

```
match /events/{eventId} {
     allow create: if request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
     allow update: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid && request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
     allow delete: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
     allow read: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
}
```

After setting there rules, directy after creating an event and setting a Snapshot listener to it, I get a:

```
EventMainActivity: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

After a small amount of time, the same action works fine (similar to running the app without security rules).

Is there supposed to be a delay like this? Note that I have only tested this in debug mode on emulators.

Comment: This is a known issue in Cloud Firestore at the moment, also surfaced in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818878/firestore-rule-failing-while-using-get-on-newly-created-documents/47837975#47837975.

The only known workaround at the moment is to add a delay before reading back the document. Sorry about that!