# firestore batch.commit() succeeds but doc.get() fails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a react app that uses firebase as the backend.

I have a workflow where I do a commit 4 documents using batch.commit()

```
batch.set(key1, obj1)
batch.set(key2, obj2)
batch.set(key3, obj3)
batch.set(key4, obj4)
let promise = batch.commit()
```

My understanding is that once the promise resolves, the documents have been written to the backend.

Immediately after this however, if I do

```
db.collection(collectionKey).doc(key1).get()
```

I get  the error

> missing or insufficient permissions

However, if i continue trying to get the doc, **that get call eventually comes back with the expected document after about 3-5s.**

am i doing something wrong? Is this expected beta behavior?

I found this post which seemed to indicate this is a known issue but this is such a basic use case I'm almost certain the error is with my implementation.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/get$20latency%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/MpS6C-ZxdZ0/EYNWdveIAwAJ

any insight apprecieated.

--------update for Jen Person ------------

I'm actually doing an async/await. but i also tried doing a regular promise.then( callback)

```
try{
    await batch.commit(dataArr)
} catch (err){
    console.error('Error Batch Saving', err)
    throw err;
}
this.setState({isProcessing: false})
```

my get function is actually inside a onClick handler. the component that registers the onClick is only visible after the batch.commit promise resolves and this.state.isProcessing is false

i also tried something like

```
db.collection(collectionKey).doc(key1).get()
    .then( res=>{
        this.setState({isProcessing:false})
    })
```

Comment: Can you show where you're resolving the work before calling `.get()`? Presumably you'll be doing something like `promise.then(() => {
    db.collection(collectionKey).doc(key1).get()
});`

Comment: This is a known issue at the moment, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818878/firestore-rule-failing-while-using-get-on-newly-created-documents

Comment: dammit. thats unfortunate and frustrating. At least i'm not crazy. is there a issue or something i can watch ?